# Jmeter: How can we combine all same get request result into one to get avargae result on summary report?

Tags: jmeter, jmx, jmeter-plugins

I have run jmter test from terminal with 30 threads and got csv result. I want to get data in format of summary report as in jmeter GUI.

I upload the csv file in summary report but it display same request multiple time as it was run with 30 threads.
Is it possible to combine all same data into one? So, that we can analyze the average result of all request.

I am gettting following result currenlty:
[image]

And I am trying to get result like this:

I want to have one same request: https://osdotme.dev/karma-program/ instead of duplicate data.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a bug in JMeter, it worth raising it via [JMeter Bugzilla](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html).

These additional results are due to [redirects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) or downloading [embedded resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses) or both

If you need this data right away you can consider the following approaches:

1. [Generate HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_only) out of the .csv file

   ```
   ./jmeter -g /Users/apple/report/jmeter/browse1.csv -o /Users/apple/report/jmeter/dashboard
   ```

The dashboard will have the summary table without these subresults

2. Use [JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) to generate the CSV form of the Summary Report in command-line without having to open JMeter GUI, add Listener, etc

   ```
   ./JMeterPluginsCMD.sh--generate-csv summary.csv --input-jtl /Users/apple/report/jmeter/browse1.csv --plugin-type SynthesisReport
   ```

   in this case `summary.csv` will be in the format you're looking for.